# @try equivalent in Swift?

Tags: exception, try-catch, swift

**ANSWER TO SUGGESTION:**

I'm using 3rd party classes from CGMathParser that throw exceptions whenever the user types invalid strings. I don't think the solution mentioned in your link can help me. Or maybe yes, but I can't figure out how

As the title suggest I need @try equivalent in Swift for this purpose:

**Obj-C:**

```
@try {
  //Some code
}
@catch (NSException* error) {
  //Catch exception if raised          
}
```

**Swift ?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm using 3rd party classes from CGMathParser that throw exceptions whenever the user types invalid strings. I don't think the solution mentioned in your link can help me. Or maybe yes, but I can't figure out how

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any try/catch support in swift. It may come eventually